# Though i'm increasing UITableViewCell height on storyboard it is not seen on device or simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I am getting problem in increasing cell height of a tableView i am using configure cell here and image view with a tag. Though I am increasing height on storyboard in attribute pane using custom row height but it is not reflecting in simulator or Device.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

     UIButton *detailbtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,96, 60, 30)];
     [detailbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     detailbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
     [detailbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-detail.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:detailbtn];

     UIButton *imageDetailbtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y+10,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height-100)];
     [imageDetailbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     imageDetailbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
     [imageDetailbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:imageDetailbtn];



     // [btn setTitle:@"Detail" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     UIButton *likebtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,96, 110, 30)];
     [likebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    likebtn.tag = indexPath.row;
     [likebtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     NSString *likes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.devices valueForKey:@"total_likes"]];

     [likebtn setTitle:likes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [cell.contentView addSubview:likebtn];

     NSLog(@"sender.tag cell is % ld ",(long)detailbtn.tag);

     // Configure Table View Cell
     NSLog(@"indexpath is%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
     [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Fetch Record
    NSManagedObject *record = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Update Cell
    //  [cell.textLabel setText:[record valueForKey:@"clip_name"]];

    UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:110];
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",K_Server_imageurl,[record valueForKey:@"clip_image_path"]]]];

    UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:111];

    [lbl setText:[record valueForKey:@"clip_name"]];

    lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: Try setting the height in -(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  return height_value; }

Comment: @JennyJose  But it should increase the height if i increase the row height on storyboard.

Comment: thanks for the answer i will try that @JennyJose

Comment: vicky check my detailed answer

Comment: Hey Vicki,  I got your problem. It works from storyboard also. Check my update

Answer (score 2):

Implement UITableViewDelegate method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

If its a static height you want, set it in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return height_value;
}
```

In Storyboard , just make sure Table's row height is set. It doesn't matter if you set only the Table View Cell's Row height. Check the screenshots 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open Storyboard and select your cell - > goto size inspector -> check the checkbox for Row height to enable custom height. otherwise it will use default height.

See Below Image
[image: Select UITableViewCell In storyboard]

**Or**

//Override following method

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    //return float value
    //e.g. return 56;
    return height;
}
```

**Or**

You can also set like following if all the row has same height

```
 self.myTableView.rowHeight = 50;
```

Comment: Its not a good practice to copy other's answer! I could easily DOWNVOTE your answer but I am gently requesting you to MIND IT next time !!

Comment: @JennyJose i know you are the great developer. But check the time of answer. we both add our answers at same time and both are not similar. If you still think it's copied please go ahead and DOWNVOTE My Answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set height table view cell row  use

```
#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate Method

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 44;  // It is the Default height of tableView
    or
  return yourHeightValue; //Whatever you want give here
}
```

From above coding

1. `UITableView` has a property named `rowHeight`, with which you can use to set all the `UITableViewCell` to the same row height;
2. If you implement the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol , and include `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method, it's you responsbility to decide the current `UITableViewCell'height`. In practice, we always use the delegate method to set the cell's height, only if each cell's height may be dynamic! And the method is preference to the `UITableView`'s `rowHeight` property!